# Override preflight request status from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cors

I'm writing a chrome extension for some site that is rather buggy.

The site has an REST-like API, and my extension successfully works with this API via `fetch` calls from content script. In particular, the site sets proper CORS headers on successfull calls to the API.

However, if any error occurs, the API response has an error HTTP code and no CORS headers. Moreover, in some cases the server returns an error HTTP code even for preflight requests (not the main requests).

As a result, in case of an error, my code can not acces any information about the response, while I would like to get the http status code of the response.

(There are two main  kinds of errors: first are really caused by a wrong request, e.g. a 404 code if I specify a wrong product id in the api call; second are spurious 500 codes which can usually be resolved by simply repeating the same request. I would like to display an error to the user in case of former errors, but to silently repeat the request in the latter case.)

I've managed to overcome the problem of missing CORS headers by using declarativeNetRequest  feature and by adding needed CORS headers to any server response.

However, I'm stuck on the problem of error HTTP status codes on preflight requests. In such a case, I naturally get a "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status", and my extension code can not even access the response status code.

So, **is there any way for a chrome extension to access the http status code of a failed preflight request?** Or probably I can outright disable preflight requests for a particular site, or any other workaround?

I have tried to add a declarativeNetRequest redirect rule for 'options' method to an empty document, but after this all preflight requests silently fail with ERR_FAILED, and even chrome's netlog does not reveal anything enlightning. (And if I change the method to 'get' in the declarativeNetRequest rule, the rule works perfectly for get requests, so it does not seem to be a problem of a rule.)